# How to generate pdf from multiple html files using puppeteer asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, puppeteer

I want to generate pdf from multiple html files, later I will merge them, once they all generated. But I am getting  error, when i try using loop. 
Can anyone tell me, How to generate pf using puppeteer from multiple html files ?
Thanks.

Comment: please share the error and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to the HTML page using [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options), and then you can generate a PDF of the page using [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions):

```
const html_files = [
  'example-1.html',
  'example-2.html',
  'example-3.html',
];

for (let i = 0, total = html_files.length; i < total; i++) {
  await page.goto(html_files[i]);

  await page.pdf({
    path: `example-pdf-${i}.pdf`,
  });
}
```

Comment: Am I blind or does this just create 3 separate files without ever merging them?